# substring assignment to limit data to custom field

Tags: apex, substring

I have a custom object with a custom field Message__c designed to hold 4000 characters.  However, the getBody in rare circumstances has exceeded the 4000 character limit and caused an error.  I have made several attempts to limit the max value that can go to 4000 characters by way of substring but test class is failing and the only change I made is changing the assignment from logRecord.Message__c = response.getBody() to the code you see below.

My goal is to limit the size of characters to 4000 so I won't get this error.

```
string getBodyString        = response.getBody();
getBodyString               = getBodyString.substring(0,3999);

logRecord.Status_Code__c    = response.getStatusCode();
logRecord.Status__c         = response.getStatus();
logRecord.Message__c        = getBodyString;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of tuncating your self why not let salesforce truncate it for you using dml options?

```
string getBodyString        = response.getBody();
logRecord.Status_Code__c    = response.getStatusCode();
logRecord.Status__c         = response.getStatus();
logRecord.Message__c        = getBodyString;

Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.allowFieldTruncation = true;
logRecord.setOptions(dmo);
insert logRecord;
```

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm

Edit: For adding it to List use Database.insert

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.allowFieldTruncation = true;
Database.insert(myLoggerList,dmo);
```

By this way in future, if you increase the character limit of your field, you don't have to deploy your code again.

Comment: I was not aware of that option.  This sounds like an ideal solution.  I was looking into the getDescribe to replace the hardcoded value but this is better.

Comment: Well I tried it and ran into this:  Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setOptions(Database.DMLOptions) from the type List<MDM_Logger__c>

Comment: @Daryn are you using setOptions on list or on individual record. U can use it only on individual records. For using it on List you have to use database.insert method. Edited answer to reflect it.

Comment: Seems to be working...  Great solution...  Thank you!